# Setting up Multiple ASP.NET MVC Endpoints with a Single SQL Server Connection in Aspire

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, dotnet-aspire

I recently attended .NET Conf 2023 where Aspire in .NET was introduced. I am working on a project and need guidance on how to set up multiple endpoints in a solution using Aspire. Currently, all three endpoints are connecting to a local SQL Server.

I want to modify the configuration so that all three endpoints connect to a single SQL Server. I would like to establish a dependency between these three endpoints and the SQL Server, making it easy to launch all three endpoints simultaneously. The endpoints are of type MVC ASP.NET.

My AppHost program.cs code :

```
var builder = DistributedApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.AddProject<Projects.CarRental_EndPoint_Admin_Web>("admin");

builder.AddProject<Projects.CarRental_EndPoint_Renter_Web>("renter");

builder.AddProject<Projects.CarRenter_EndPoint_Rentor_Web>("rentor");

builder.Build().Run();
```

1. How can I configure a shared SQL Server connection that serves as a dependency for all three endpoints?
2. Once the SQL Server dependency is established, how can I access and use it within each endpoint's code?

Comment: Do you want to run SQL server in a container or connect to one on your machine?

Answer (score 0):

just go ahead to code.

AppHost Program.cs:

```
var builder = DistributedApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

var sql = builder.AddSqlServerContainer("sql",password:"Str0ngP@ssW0rd",port:12345).AddDatabase("CarRental");

var backend = builder.AddProject<Projects.CarRental_EndPoint_API>("backend").WithReference(sql);

builder.AddProject<Projects.CarRental_EndPoint_Admin_Web>("frontendadmin").WithReference(backend);

builder.AddProject<Projects.CarRental_Persistence>("database").WithReference(sql);

builder.Build().Run();
```

and add `builder.AddSqlServerDbContext<DataBaseContext>("CarRental");` to my endpoints.